# Undo changes AFTER Macro has run (NOT undoing macro itself)

Tags: excel, vba, undo

Using Office 365
Cannot undo any manual Actions in the xlsm spreadsheet.
Macro is fine...DON'T need to undo macro actions, but hoping to find a way to undo any manual entries made AFTER macro has done its thing.

Once macro has finished, users can continue to manually edit sheet.
If they make a mistake at any point, "undo" is not available.

Sheet5 has `Worksheet_Change` that is looking at 2 specific cells to trigger actions:
`K7` to check for duplicate file name, and `H297` to jump to the top of page instead of scrolling all the way up.

code example:

```vb
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H297")) Is Nothing Then
Application.Goto Reference:=Range("A1")
```

Doing anything, anywhere else in the sheet still greys out Undo function.

`Sheet2` doesn't have any codes. Can't undo anything in that sheet either.

Expected:

- Macro runs on `Workbook_Open`
- UNDO is greyed out (don't need to undo macro steps)
- type something in any cell (i.e. `B20`)
- UNDO should be available, as I'm not changing target cells `K7` or `H297`?

Any way to enable Undo for simple things like typing in non-targeted cells?
Or, is there a different way to actually target the cells...maybe `If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H297")) Is Nothing` can be entered differently?

To me it looks like targeting specific cells is not working correctly?
It looks like `Worksheet_Change` keeps looking for ANY type of change in the sheet and is clearing Undo stack with change to ANY cell.

Any way to deal with this? Or is it "just the way it is" with Macro workbook?

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("K7")) Is Nothing Then
        Call POexists ' (macro to look in taget folder to see if assigned number in cell K7 exists)
    End If
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H297")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.Goto Reference:=Range("A1") ' (jump to top of page once H297 has any value)
        Range("K7").Select
    End If
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("K7")) Is Nothing Then
        Call ScrollButton ' (button to jump to bottom of sheet - can be removed for this code)
    End If
    
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A:$AC"

End Sub
```

Comment: Application.EnableEvents = False    Application.Undo     Application.EnableEvents = True       This was suggested somewhere, but it shows error "Method Undo of _Application failed"

Comment: In the moment you modify *anything* (data, format...) via VBA-Code, Undo is no longer available (for modifications that where done before the code execution)

Comment: Why don't you share both event codes (as text) so we could figure out what is happening?

Comment: If Undo is being erased in `Sheet2` when you dont have code there, it sounds like you might have a `Workbook_SheetChange` event or something else that is happening to your workbook. If you add your code to the post, it would be easier to diagnose the problem.

Comment: > UNDO should be available, as I'm not changing target cells K7 or H297
`Worksheet_Change` doesn't work like that. It fires for any change you have made. Just because your listener isn't changing anything, doesn't mean it isn't running.

Comment: Thanks for your replies everyone. As some of you have pointed out, it looks like Worksheet_Change is telling it to keep looking for ANY change regardless of Target, and therefore it constantly clears Undo stack.

Comment: So do you know how to fix it?

Comment: The `Worksheet_Change`-event alone doesn't clears the Undo-stack. It is cleared when within that routine anything is changed in the Excel sheet

Comment: From everything I could find online, and the way sheet behaves, it does look like "Worksheet_Change" is clearing Undo stack regardless of whether anything is actually changed in set Target Range. I will post the only  "Worksheet_Change" that exists in this workbook (can't find a way to attach document). Unless someone has other suggestions after seeing the code, I think I'll just get rid of Worksheet_Change. It's just unfortunate that I made 140 documents already before realizing this Undo problem :(